# How to match a map with a trajectory using PC tools

Tags: google-maps, coordinates

I have the following problem and I think with the appropriate tools (hopefully open source) it can be solved, but I don't know which.

I have a trajectory from a point (0,0) with other points (X,Y) with units in meters. They correspond to an actual vehicle moving in a city.
I know the approximate location of the streets it happened.

I went to google maps and lo and behold there is the streets where the trajectory takes place.

I want to match this trajectory to the map. (It can be google maps, or other map ).

There are some hardships:

1. I don't know the exact location in the map of (0,0)
2. The x,y axis of my trajectory do not coincide with the axis of the map so I might have to rotate the trajectory

How can I match the map (google maps, open street maps, etc) with the trajectory I have (I have it both as coordinates of my local coordinate system and as a matplotlib visualization) so that I can superimpose the trajectory on the map?

Ideally I need a tool where I can move the trajectory as well as rotate it and that both have the same scale

Comment: I would suggest asking https://gis.stackexchange.com/ regarding such topics.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Alright, thanks I will do.  should I delete this question after I do?

Comment: @u1686_grawity The reason I did not want to post this there was because it is conterproductive.  They are professionals in geographic information systems and therefore tend to overcomplicate things (as it happened). My problem is much more simpler.

Comment: @KansaiRobot Fair enough.